# Why can I resize a QFile being used in an application?

Tags: macos, qt, qfile

Quite simple question, but can't find an answer. I have developed an app on OSX (Yosemite) using Qt Creator, so basically I have some files in Center.app . When I open this application, I can do something like :

```
QFile file("Center.app/Contents/MacOS/Center");
file.resize(0);
```

And my application is still running! But when I close it and try to re-open it, it doesn't work (seems pretty normal).
So my question is, why is that possible?

**Bonus :** How can I test if such a file is being used? On windows, file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) returns false when the .exe is running and true when it's not, but on Mac OS, it returns true everytime...

Comment: The OS may load the entire application into memory and close the file, thus leaving it accessible (readable/writable) to any process.

Comment: Why is it like this on OSX and not on Windows then?

Comment: Because different os behave differently when dealing with launching an executable. Windows might be more conservative to avoid people cutting the branch tree on which they sit

Comment: Mmh ok, thanks to both of you @owacoder and bibi. Does that mean that there's no way to check if a file in the .app is being used?

Comment: It is probably not even being used (just a guess, although I never used Mac). This behavior is really OS-specific. For example, Linux allows to delete a running executable, HP-UX doesn't, but allows to rename it (so you can rename a running file, then put the new version in place of it and then later delete the old one when it's no longer used).

Comment: Oh ok! I understand better now. What a strange behavior... (or maybe Windows is behaving weirdly? ;) ) Thanks for your answer as well Sergey !

Comment: Linux and many if not almost all unixes (which includes OS X) behave that way. It's windows here that's different :) (and annoying). The trick is that the file isn't actually deleted, just removed from indexes, so applications having a file descriptor for it can keep using it.

Comment: For reference, in unix/linux/posix'ish OSes, the system call to delete a file is often referred to as "unlink()" because it simply unlinks or detaches the file from the filesystem. This allows all programs already operating on the file to continue doing so, but the file won't show up in the directory listing.